# Add shapefile to ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, ggmap

Somewhat similar to the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084609/im-having-trouble-adding-a-shapefile-to-my-ggmap-due-to-differing-geographic-un) I am having troubles aligning a shapefile and ggmap object.

1. My shapefile consists of local area boundaries in Victoria, Australia, and I am trying to overlay them on top of a google map of the state (Victoria).

   The source shapefile has the following PROJ4 string (extracted from the prj file)

   ```
   [+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs]
   ```

   which corresponds to [EPSG:4283](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4283).

   Here's the summary of my shapefile object `sp`:

   ```
   > summary(sp)
   Object of class SpatialPolygonDataFrame
   Coordinates:
           min        max
   x  96.81677 159.109219
   y -43.74051  -9.142176
   Is projected: FALSE
   proj4string:
   [+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs]
   ```
2. I convert the shapefile to match google's pseudo Mercator projection (at least that's what I think I'm doing)

   ```
   sp <- spTransform(sp, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:3857"))
   ```

   and turn `sp` into a fortified dataframe `df.sp`.
3. I then use

   ```
   map <- get_map("Victoria", zoom = 7, maptype = "terrain", source = "google")
   ```

   to get a google terrain map of Victoria, and (gg)plot them

   ```
   ggmap(map) + geom_polygon(data = df.sp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + coord_equal() + theme_map()
   ```

[image: Map of Victoria]

It's clear from the resulting plot that shapefile coordinates and googlemap coordinates don't overlap. Am I doing something wrong with the coordinate transformation? How do I properly match shapefile and googlemap coordinates? I would appreciate any help/insight into this matter.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I've got an example of plotting Victorian polygons on a Google Map in the [vignette of my googleway package](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/vignettes/googleway-vignette.Rmd#polygon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my first post, so forgive me if the styling isn't fantastic. I found for whatever reason, the default `ESPG:3857` in the `rgdal` package wasn't transforming the projection correctly in the `spTransform` function.

- Using [gene's wonderful answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64654/choosing-the-correct-value-for-proj4string-for-shapefile-reading-in-r-maptools) in GIS StackExchange, I was directed to the [`Prj2EPSG`](http://www.prj2epsg.org/search) website and the [Spatial Reference](http://spatialreference.org/) website. I double checked the ABS's `proj4` string (I assume that's where this data has come from) and it's as you've said (which is `EPSG:4283`).
- When entering EPSG:3857 into the Spatial reference I got this string (using the Proj4 link) `+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`.
- I replaced `+proj=merc` with `+proj=longlat` to project the longitude and latitude co-ordinates.
- Using that string with `merc` replaced seems to give me better results than using just `+init=epsg:3857`, which indicated to me there's some difference in the way the rgdal package handles it.

I'd love to hear of a way to improve on this further, but I'm hoping maybe this can help you get better results in the meantime.

---

**EDIT:** I've also found that when plotting using `ggplot2` adding `coord_map()` seems to fix the shape files' alignment when up close, but leave them a little off when zoomed out further. At zoom scales 7 and above I seem to get perfect alignment, but 6 and lower and I don't. It seems that for whatever reason the different zoom levels change the projection slightly.

So try

```
ggmap(map) + 
  geom_polygon(data = df.sp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  coord_equal() + 
  theme_map() + 
  coord_map()
```